# How do I download a buffer file which is stored in memory in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file, multer

**Explanation**: So, basically I am trying to make a express.js website where I can upload files and it gets saved in the database and users can download them later on. So, my idea was to convert the file (.jar , .txt and .json) into buffer data and store it in MongoDB. And then fetch the buffer data from MongoDB and download that file. So, I read through the docs and couldn't find anything that does this.

**Code**: There is nothing really to show, I have a variable which has buffer data and I am using "express.js@4.17.1".

For testing, I am currently uploading the file using multer and once I click "upload", I am trying to download the same file to save time(instead of saving and fetching from database), so the buffer data is currently stored in "req.file.buffer". When I log "req.file" , I get this

```js
console.log(req.file)
```

```
{
  fieldname: 'fileupload',
  originalname: 'jg.txt',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'text/plain',
  buffer: <Buffer >,
  size: 0
}
```

**Conclusion**: I want to convert the buffer data (req.file.buffer) into a downloadable file which the user can download(later on, make it such that it can be sent as a email attachment but both of them requires a file path and name, so once I figure out how to do the express.js thing, I can do the mail thing too). I have read many articles which first saves the buffer data into a file and then uploads, but I want to do without that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
res.set({
  "Content-Type": <content type of your file>,
  "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=<name of your file>"
});
res.end(req.file.buffer);
```

This first sets the headers that cause the browser to download the file, then sends the file contents.

But your `req.file.buffer` seems to be an empty buffer, so the upload has perhaps not worked?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will test it in a bit, also the buffer is empty because cmd isn't displaying it as it is inside an object but I have checked and it isn't empty :)